# How to find token for Google sheet API v4

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-ruby-client

I am using ruby to read google sheet by using steps given here:

[Ruby Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/ruby)

Anyone, please let me know the structure of `token.yml` or where to find this file.

Answer (score 1):

TOKEN_PATH is just the directory where you want the tokens saved.  So

```
TOKEN_PATH = 'token.yaml'.freeze
```

is just a directory its not really a file.